# Dismatch method on Inputing and uploading?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post, get

Im developing web site with php and ajax, i have problems,when i am inputing data i use Get method on Ajax but when i want to upload image i must use POST method because we can upload just with POST Method,soz how to get file name for inputing to db but when inputing and uploading not same method ? I need the logic

or anyidea for inputing and uploading ? soz already make whole web with get method that is probly if change to method post

thanks for helping,Best regard

Comment: can't you use a ready production script for uploading your files?

Comment: You're Stack Overflow :D, checkout [this](https://github.com/valums/file-uploader) great script for ajax style file upload!

Comment: are you trying to read file input from `$_FILES` array in your `action.php` ?

Comment: H4bo u are right i need read $_FILES but cant catch it

Comment: Hey Stack Overflow, check out Related Questions on your right-side of this page.

Answer (score 0):

can you use third party uploader.

http://fineuploader.com/

This plugin is open sourced under MIT license, GNU GPL 2 or later and GNU LGPL 2 or later.

use this AJAX fileuploader it has highly migrated functionalities.

hope this will help.feel free to ask anything.